# Understanding Ajax and adding cart count

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

website: https://www.fermento24.com
If you add a product to the cart, it'll show you the recently added product, total and possibility to go to cart. What I wanted to add was a count of the sort, like: There are currently another 5 products in the cart.

I tried to use {{ cart.item_count }}, but since the popup works on Ajax it doesn't seem to update on time, only showing me at the first time how many products were in the cart (thus, incorrect informations).

How do I go and implement something like this? What follows under is a test I did based on other answers I found here, but that still didn't work.

```html
<div class="loading-modal modal">{{ 'general.search.loading' | t }}</div> 

<div class="newsletter-success-modal">
  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
  <div class="ajax-modal-content">
    <a class="close close-window btn" title="{{ 'general.password_page.close' | t }}">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>{{ 'general.newsletter_form.mailing_list_success_message' | t }}</span>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="ajax-error-modal modal">
  <div class="modal-inner">
    <div class="ajax-error-title">{{ 'general.search.error' | t }}</div>
    <div class="ajax-error-message"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ajax-success-modal modal">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content"> 
      
      
      <div class="ajax-left">    
        <p class="added-to-cart info">{{ 'cart.general.added_to_cart' | t }}</p>
      <p class="added-to-wishlist info">{{ 'products.wishlist.added_to_wishlist' | t }}</p>
      <img class="ajax-product-image" alt="modal window" src="/" />
       <div class="ajax-cart-desc">
        <h3 class="ajax-product-title"></h3>
        <span class="ajax_price"></span>
        <p>{{ 'cart.general.qty' | t }}:&nbsp;<span class="ajax_qty"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ajax-right"> 
      
        <div>Totale nel carrello: <span class="ajax_cartTotal"></span><br>
          <span class="cart-item-count"> </span>
        </div>
          <button class="btn continue-shopping" onclick="javascript:void(0)">{{ 'cart.general.continue_shopping' | t }}</button>
        <div class="success-message added-to-cart"><a href="/cart" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>{{ 'cart.general.view_cart' | t }}</a> </div>  
      
      </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
    </div>    
</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var cartCount = {{ cart.item_count }};
    $('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            data: {
                quantity: 1,
                id: $(this).attr("data-variant")
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/cart.json',
                    success: function(cart){
                        cartCount++;
                        $('.cart-item-count').html(cartCount);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the code and your JS code is looks like similar to demo code below:

```
$(function(){
    $('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            data: {
                quantity: 1,
                id: $(this).attr("data-variant")
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/cart.js',
                    success: function(cart){
                        // once you get the data from AJAX API you need to get the latest count
                        let total = cart.item_count;
                        $('.cart-item-count').html(total);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the reference for the `cart.js` over Shopify documentation.
[Link](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart)
[image]

Comment: Think you could explain where I should add the Js you showed me?  I tried to figure it out but couldn't find it...

Comment: Okay, need to update the content and counter into the popup that comes after the item added to the cart, right?

Comment: Yes, I tired to add your code in a <script> in the modal and then add a div with the class needed, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this the popup where you want to update the data or quantity after add to cart completed?https://prnt.sc/wmpze1

Comment: Exactly!. And the code that I've written in the post is the inside of this popup.

Comment: according to the codeshare into the post, the `ajax_qty` is the element class that handles the count and it is updated into `shop.js`. https://prnt.sc/wmqt5x

Comment: Yeah but the class ajax_qty shows only the quantity of the current product added, while I'm trying to show the quantity of the total amount of products in cart at the moment. 
Ecample: I have already 3 products into the cart, if I add a new product it should tell me: Total product amount: 4 products. It instead shows "1" because you add 1 product to the cart.

Comment: Okay, got it. I have shared the code you can check try it. https://prnt.sc/wmr59u
 ( https://gist.github.com/o-nkar/0860ce74f900d430f88a3fc670ef45b6)

Comment: Sorry if I've only just answered. It worked. I didn't comment the other part because I need that too, and added this as another ajax_qtyA, so thank you very much.